# How do i get past the second part of the Slimescraper?

Tags: fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

Once you get past the bumpers, you are challenged with a bunch of really small laser floors that turn on and off.  I have tried, but I can't get past them.  I am always bumped by another player, or I barely miss and fall to the floor, where I have to start over.  By my third attempt the slime hits me and I'm eliminated.  I tried to figure out the pattern of how they turn on and off, but it seems completely random.  I have tried walking on the thin platforms on the edge of the lasers, but it seems very finicky, sometimes I walk just fine, other times I slide off.

How do I cross these effectively?

I would just keep trying, but since it doesn't come that often it's hard to practice, and I just need to know if something I've tried won't work so I won't waste my time trying again.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing is pretty simple to figure out, what most people seem to struggle with is that they aren't connected to each other or the edges so you have to jump, not walk.

However, the easiest way is to jump on he bits on the side because they don't disappear.

Comment: yeah, I've done it now.  You just have to make sure you jump and figure out the timing.  thnx

Comment: finished the whole level for the first time!  One of my high moments in the game, lol.

Comment: I've figured it out now, and for anyone else reading this, here's important advice.  DO NOT GET HIT BY THE BUMPERS THAT COME BEFORE THIS SECTION.  If you do you will stumble, and get trampled by them mob, which will mean you will have to deal with more people who will bump you and keep you from getting through, all while the slime gets closer and closer.  I've gotten across this part every time I've avoided this.  Hope it helps!